# GridBagLayout don't take all the window place

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Hi have a very simple question, why my gridBagLayout don't take all the disponible place on my window ?

here the code :

```
public class FenConnection extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4799549157439445680L;

    private String adresse;
    private int port;

    private JLabel infoLabel;
    private JTextField tf_adresse;
    private JButton boutonConnexion;
    private JTextField tf_port;

    public FenConnection()
    {
        super();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(400, 150);
        this.setTitle("Felix - Connexion");

        adresse = Felix.CONFIGURATION.getString("ADRESSE_CHAT");
        port = Integer.parseInt(Felix.CONFIGURATION.getString("PORT_CHAT"));

        construireFormulaire();
    }

    private void construireFormulaire()
    {
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        //Construction des labels
        c.gridx = 0;

        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(new JLabel("Adresse IP :"), c);

        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(new JLabel("Port :"), c);

        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        infoLabel = new JLabel("Saisir l'adresse et le port du serveur chat");
        pane.add(infoLabel, c);

        //Creation du bouton de connection
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        boutonConnexion = new JButton("Connexion");
        pane.add(boutonConnexion, c);

        //Construction des champs de texts
        c.gridx = 1;

        c.gridy = 0;
        tf_adresse = new JTextField(adresse);
        pane.add(tf_adresse, c);

        c.gridy = 1;
        tf_port = new JTextField(port);
        pane.add(tf_port, c);
    }
}
```

An other weird thing is that if I add `this.pack();` at the end of my constructor, it make a very large and buggy windows... I don't why.

I have used this Layout many times and I have never view the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ho... Yes sorry it's perhaps dificult to test... Do I have to put the whole class ?

Comment: Edited with the whole code class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're letting the weightx and weighty attributes default to 0 which means they will not fill the available space.

Try adding non-zero for weightx and weighty

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I've forgotten this ^^